# Angular2 ngFor does not see updated data within directive callback function

Tags: angular

I have read various ideas of how to make the angular 2 detection system update the DOM, and I can not seem to get this working. Essentially, I want to make an infinite scroller, and I would like a callback function that is declared within the view to be called at the appropriate time by the directive. Eg, if the distance to the bottom of the page is less than 50 px, then call the callback, then update the data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hFCUQCYHprVn1XxcuKnT?p=preview

So it looks like this:

```
@Component...
template: '<div *ngFor="#item in items" infinity-scroller [scrollerCallback]="scrollCallback">{{item}}</div>'

constructor () {
  this.items = getMockData(0, 40)
  this.onScrollCallback = this.onScrollCallback.bind(this)
}

addData () {
  this.items.push(...getMockData(410, 500))
}

onScrollCallback (ctx) {
  this.items = this.items.concat(getMockData(50, 100))
}

@Directive
selector: '[infinity-scroller]'
inputs: ['scrollerCallback']

class InfinityScroller 

ngOnInit () {
   window.onscroll = () => onScroll(this)
}

function onScroll (ctx) {
   ... logic to call the callback function (ie, ctx.scrollerCallback())
}
```

I added the addData method to test adding data to the view, and that function works perfectly. I click a button, and addData pushes the new items to the array and the view updates.

however, when the callback in the directive makes the call to the inputed "scrollCallback" function, updating the data is not reflected in the DOM.

Any idea why this would be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular change detection doesn't recognize change detection on arrays or objects when only the content changes but not the array or object itself.

```
this.items.push(...getMockData(410, 500))
this.items = this.items.slice(); // add this line to make Angular recognize the change.
```

If you bind to a property of the item Angular recognizes the changes as well.

Comment: Hi Gunter. Thanks for the response. Two things that i wasn't clear about in the question, so sorry about that: 1. I have tried two methods of updating the data: one by doing data.push(...newData) and two data = data.concat(newData). The first keeps the same reference, and the second makes a new one. 2. The update is **only** failing inside the callback function, not inside the addData method. So i have a button in my template to run the addData method, and I see the data correctly added. But when the callback adds the data, it fails.

Comment: Another thing I tried that is really bizare: the onScroll event is firing correctly and calling the callback function where I do this.data.push(...getMockData()), but the view doesn't update. Console logging shows the data was added to this.data, however. Then, if I click the button to run the addData method, all of the data shows up! So inside of adding 40 more items like I set it up to, it shows 500+ more, because of all of the times it was called during scrolling and adding new data.

Comment: Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a few things in your code that look weird. This line `this.onScrollCallback = this.onScrollCallback.bind(this)` and `function` in this line `function onScroll (ctx) {`. It's hard to see from your code how the things are connected. Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: An interesting thing to try is to remove the `this.onScrollCallback = this.onScrollCallback.bind(this)` and see that this will be from the context of the directive, not the component (within the onScroll callback)

Comment: Just a note: By adding `ngFor` and `infinity-scroller` on the same div, you create a new `InfinityScroller` for each `item` in `data`.

Comment: Instead of passing a callback around, I would instead use an output (`myScroll`) in your `InfinityScroller` and then use it like `<div infinity-scroller (myScroll)="onScrollCallback($event")></div>`. Then you don't have issues with context. Otherwise I guess I can't provide any more help.